# Unclickable Content Outside Max-Width

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, flexbox, overflow

I created a datepicker component in Vue that I'm trying to use in a standard Bootstrap column layout. The problem is that when the columns are smaller than the select window for the datepicker, any area outside the div is unclickable. So in the picture below, all the dates on the far right column cannot be selected.

Widening the wrapping div does allow the content to be clicked, so I know it has to do with the datepicker overflowing past the boundary set by the wrapper divs max-width.

Is there any way to still achieve what is seen visually in the image but allow user interactions to be detected on elements that overflow outside the wrapper?

[image: Div outline with content overflowing]

```css
.row {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    margin-right: -15px;
    margin-left: -15px;
}

@media (min-width: 576px){
.col-sm-3 {
    flex: 0 0 25%;
    max-width: 25%;
}}

.datepicker {
width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div data-v-44ab1ae6="" class="row">
<div data-v-44ab1ae6="" class="col-sm-3 col-12">
<div class="datepicker"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Applying `position: relative` and `z-index` to the datepicker div should place the div above the other content while keeping the overflowing content clickable.

I've used bootstrap-vue for the markup, but the end result should be the same as they're both utilizing the same bootstrap CSS.

Demo:
https://codepen.io/Hiws/pen/zgRmOV